# Auto-complete box with drop-down

Tags: c#, silverlight, autocompletebox

The [`AutoCompleteBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox(v=vs.95).aspx) is pretty great, but one feature it lacks is a click-to-drop-down all the available options.  You can come close by setting `MinimumPrefixLength`=0 -- that way, the user can get the complete drop-down list by deleting the text.  This has a couple of limitations, though:

- if there is no text to begin with, then the user would have to enter some text and delete it (non-intuitive and inconvenient)
- the click-and-keypress sequence seems like suboptimal UX.

How would you tweak this control to make it drop down the complete list of options, when the user clicks on the control (or, also fine, a button to the right)?

---

It seems I have disappointed @HighCore.  So far I tried adding a button to the control template, which triggers opening the Popup.  The drawback to this approach is that, if there is text entered, then the list will be filtered per the normal filtering rules.  Now, you *could* clear the text, thus removing the filter, but this has another side effect: de-selecting the currently selected item (in contrast to a ComboBox, whose drop-down you can open without de-selecting).  So ... what now?  Temporarily remove the filter, and restore it when the popup is closed or the user types anything else?

Comment: turn the entire thing into a `ToggleButton`, similar to what the default Template for the `ComboBox` does when `IsEditable="False"`. That way, clicking on any part of the entire visual will show the dropdown

Comment: BTW, I feel sad about having to ask this to a 56k rep user here in SO, but what have you tried?

Comment: @HighCore I'm a bit taken aback to discover someone reading Silverlight questions, to be honest ... I was planning to self-answer if I ever get around to it, but thought I would check to see if anyone here has already solved this particular problem.

Comment: @McCarnagle shouldn't be too hard or complicated IMO, just override the Control Template and create a new one incorporating the concept I mentioned from the ComboBox template.

Comment: @McCarnagle after reading your edit, I thought: why not just `var item = this.SelectedItem` and then `this.Text = string.empty` and then `this.SelectedItem = item` ?

Comment: @HighCore well, setting `SelectedItem` directly resets `Text`.  But using the ListBox template part seems to work (set SelectedItem + ScrollIntoView).  Anyway, I'll post the answer when I get it worked out.

Comment: @McCarnagle I'm glad you've been able to come up with a workable approach. I'm too lazy and busy atm to answer SO questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built a control like that, the approach I used was to inherit from the AutoComboBox control and remove the filter when the dropdown opens.

***EDIT***
Code has been updated to include missing resources.

Code is:

```
public class AutoCompleteComboBox : AutoCompleteBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when drop down toggle button is clicked.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler ToggleButtonClick;

    private object _holdSelectedItem;
    private AutoCompleteFilterMode _holdFilterMode;

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the DisplayMemberPath dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMemberPath", typeof(string), typeof(AutoCompleteComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, DisplayMemberPath_PropertyChanged));
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name or path of the property 
    /// that is displayed for each the data item in the control.
    /// </summary>
    public string DisplayMemberPath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value); }
    }
    private static void DisplayMemberPath_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var accb = (AutoCompleteComboBox)d;
        accb.ValueMemberPath = e.NewValue.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the MaxLength dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxLengthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MaxLength", typeof(int), typeof(AutoCompleteComboBox), null);
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the maximum number of characters allowed for user input.
    /// </summary>
    public int MaxLength
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MaxLengthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaxLengthProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a collection used to generate the content of the control.
    /// </summary>
    public new IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty) as IEnumerable; }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, null);
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => SetValue(TextProperty, string.Empty));
            _holdSelectedItem = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the AutoCompleteComboBox control.
    /// </summary>
    public AutoCompleteComboBox()
    {
        StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/UI.Controls;component/AutoCompleteComboBox.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        var sr = new StreamReader(sri.Stream);
        Style = (Style)XamlReader.Load(sr.ReadToEnd());

        DropDownClosed += AutoCompleteComboBox_DropDownClosed;
        DropDownOpened += AutoCompleteComboBox_DropDownOpened;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the template's tree is generated.
    /// </summary>
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var toggle = (ToggleButton)GetTemplateChild("PopupToggleButton");
        toggle.Click += DropDownToggle_Click;

        var lb = (ListBox)GetTemplateChild("Selector");
        lb.DisplayMemberPath = DisplayMemberPath;
        _holdFilterMode = FilterMode;

        TextChanged += AutoCompleteComboBox_TextChanged;
        SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(AutoCompleteComboBox_SelectionChanged);
    }

    private void AutoCompleteComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<bool> e)
    {
        if (SelectedItem == null && _holdSelectedItem != null && SelectedItem != _holdSelectedItem && ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Contains(_holdSelectedItem))
        {
            SelectedItem = _holdSelectedItem;
        }
        _holdSelectedItem = null;
        FilterMode = _holdFilterMode;
    }

    private void AutoCompleteComboBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<bool> e)
    {
        var lb = (ListBox)GetTemplateChild("Selector");
        ScrollViewer sv = lb.GetScrollHost();
        if (sv != null)
        {
            sv.ScrollToTop();
        }
        if (SelectedItem != null)
        {
            lb.SelectedItem = SelectedItem;
            _holdSelectedItem = SelectedItem;
        }
    }

    private void DropDownToggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsDropDownOpen = !IsDropDownOpen;
        if (ToggleButtonClick != null)
        {
            ToggleButtonClick(this, e);
        }
        if (IsDropDownOpen)
        {
            _holdFilterMode = FilterMode;
            FilterMode = AutoCompleteFilterMode.None;
            ((TextBox)GetTemplateChild("Text")).SelectAll();
        }
        Focus();
    }

    private void AutoCompleteComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsDropDownOpen)
        {
            if (FilterMode == AutoCompleteFilterMode.None && FilterMode != _holdFilterMode)
            {
                FilterMode = _holdFilterMode;
            }
            ScrollViewer sv = ((ListBox)GetTemplateChild("Selector")).GetScrollHost();
            if (sv != null)
            {
                sv.ScrollToTop();
            }
        }
    }

    private void AutoCompleteComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsDropDownOpen && SelectedItem == null)
        {
            Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
<Setter Property="MinimumPopulateDelay" Value="1" />
<Setter Property="IsTextCompletionEnabled" Value="False" />
<Setter Property="MinimumPrefixLength" Value="0" />
<Setter Property="MaxDropDownHeight" Value="300" />
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF000000" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="45" />
<Setter Property="FilterMode" Value="Contains" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ctrls:AutoCompleteComboBox">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style x:Name="comboToggleStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#E5FFFFFF"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#BCFFFFFF"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#6BFFFFFF"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#E5FFFFFF"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#BCFFFFFF"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#6BFFFFFF"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="Background" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundOverlay" Opacity="0" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#FF448DCA" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="#00000000"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundOverlay2" Opacity="0" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#FF448DCA" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="#00000000"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="#FFFFFFFF">
                                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                                        </Rectangle>
                                        <Rectangle Opacity="0" x:Name="BackgroundOverlay3" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#FF448DCA" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="#00000000"/>
                                        <Rectangle Opacity="0" x:Name="BackgroundGradient2" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="#FFFFFFFF">
                                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                                        </Rectangle>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="Highlight" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                                        <ContentPresenter
                                                  x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusX="3.5" Margin="1"  RadiusY="3.5" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
```

---

```
                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CommonValidationToolTipTemplate" TargetType="ToolTip">
                        <Grid x:Name="Root" Margin="5,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" Opacity="0">
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="Translation" X="-25" />
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup Name="OpenStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                                        <VisualTransition To="Open" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Translation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                        <BackEase Amplitude=".3" EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Translation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" To="0" Duration="0" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <Border Margin="4,4,-4,-4" Background="#052A2E31" CornerRadius="5" />
                            <Border Margin="3,3,-3,-3" Background="#152A2E31" CornerRadius="4" />
                            <Border Margin="2,2,-2,-2" Background="#252A2E31" CornerRadius="3" />
                            <Border Margin="1,1,-1,-1" Background="#352A2E31" CornerRadius="2" />

                            <Border Background="#FFDC000C" CornerRadius="2">
                                <TextBlock UseLayoutRounding="false" Foreground="White" Margin="8,4,8,4" MaxWidth="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <TextBox x:Name="Text" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" MaxLength="{TemplateBinding MaxLength}" />
                <ToggleButton x:Name="PopupToggleButton" Width="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource comboToggleStyle}" Margin="1" >
                    <Path x:Name="BtnArrow" Height="4" Width="8" Stretch="Uniform" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BtnArrowColor" Color="#FF333333"/>
                        </Path.Fill>
                    </Path>
                </ToggleButton>
                <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" Visibility="Collapsed" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource CommonValidationToolTipTemplate}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                            <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <system:Boolean>true</system:Boolean>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </ToolTip.Triggers>
                        </ToolTip>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <Grid Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12" Background="Transparent">
                        <Path Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" />
                        <Path Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                    <ListBox x:Name="Selector" SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" />
                </Popup>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PopupStates">
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0" To="PopupOpened" />
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0" To="PopupClosed" />
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PopupOpened">
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PopupClosed">
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Valid" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <system:Boolean>True</system:Boolean>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: This is really nifty -- much better than my half-assed attempt.  My preference would be to see the text as you type, but that was easily achieved by giving "PopupToggleButton" an Opacity < 1.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else reading this answer... the only external resources missing from above are: 1) "comboToggleStyle", and 2) "ValidationToolTipTemplate".  These are default themes available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408(v=vs.95).aspx (ComboBox) and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728668(v=vs.95).aspx (AutoCompleteBox) respectively.

Comment: That is nifty, I did separate out your code chunks though for readability, and you're missing some parts like the top of your toggler thing `<Style TargetType....` and the bottom of the other one etc. Get the jist though, +1 sir

Answer (score 0):

I worked out one approach.  The basic idea is to overlay a button, either in a modified control template, or just flung on top of the view (I'll use the latter here for brevity's sake).  The button thing does three things:

1. Clear the text (in order to restore the complete unfiltered list)
2. Set `IsDropDownOpen` = true to open the Popup
3. Restore the selected item to the ListBox template child

---

So basically, I have a setup like this:

```
<Grid>
    <mycontrols:ExtendedAutoCompleteBox x:Name="autoCompleteBox" ... />
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Click">
        <Path Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z " 
              Fill="Black" Stretch="Uniform"
              Width="8" Height="4"
              />
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

The purpose of subclassing `AutoCompleteBox` is just to get access to the template child:

```
public class ExtendedAutoCompleteBox : AutoCompleteBox
{
    private ListBox _listBox;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _listBox = GetTemplateChild("Selector") as ListBox;
    }

    public void ShowAllOptions()
    {
        var selectedItem = SelectedItem;
        Text = "";
        IsDropDownOpen = true;

        _listBox.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
        UpdateLayout();
        _listBox.ScrollIntoView(selectedItem);
    }
}
```

And so the button click will just call this "ShowAllOptions":

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    autoCompleteBox.ShowAllOptions();
}
```

It's not perfect -- for some reason the keyboard controls get screwy after clicking the button (if you press enter on an item, it does not select the item, but clears it instead) -- but it is better than nothing.

So just to illustrate what it does: let's say you have an item "x" selected, and you click the arrow button, then you will see the complete list:

[image: AutoCompleteBox with drop-down]